# How to display details after clicking on table's cell filled by v-for?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a component which displays the list of 'matches' and after click on particular cell it should show the concrete information about it (with help of child's function `passData(value)`). The data is displayed via v-for in a table:

```
...
<tr v-for="(value,key) in matches" v-bind:key="(value,key)">
        <td v-on:click="passData(value)">{{value.match_id}}</td>
        <td>{{value.duration}}</td>
        <td>{{value.start_time}}</td>
        ...
        <match ref="match"></match>
</tr>
...
```

So result what I want to achive should be like this:
[image]
when a user clikcs on a match it displays a 'card' with some info about it and if the user clicks on it again it hides.
To make it clear all components are working correctly. The problem is that I can't intgrate it into the v-for method. I just need to display a 'card' on the needed place. How can I do this?

What I am having now:
[image]

Comment: You have the `match_id`s passed to a method, why can't you just render the details in "card" based on those?

Comment: @jom all the data inside the card is rendered correctly. Write now I can display a card with data about choosen match only outside the table because of v-for. I want to display it inside the table. I've added a new image to the post.

Comment: can you explain where exactly you want to show the selected data ?

Comment: @MohsinAmjad under the selected match

Comment: okay,  i am posting answer let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is something like this to show details of each row next to it if needed

```
<template v-for="(value,key) in matches">
 <tr v-bind:key="(value,key)">
        <td v-on:click="toggleData(value)">{{value.match_id}}</td>
        <td>{{value.duration}}</td>
        <td>{{value.start_time}}</td>
        ...
        <match ref="match"></match>
 </tr>
 <tr v-bind:key="`${key}_details`" v-if="details[value.match_id]">
      ... show whatever you want 
 </tr>
</template>
```

and in toggleData(value)
if not present add it else remove it

```
this.details[value.match_id] = value // if single
this.details[value.match_id] = []    // OR if multiple
this.details[value.match_id].push(value)
```